# Trouble evaluating this limit

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have to evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}n/(n^2+1) + n/(n^2+2)+n/(n^2+3)+....+n/(n^2+n)$

Now, for the rth term: $\lim_{n \to \infty}n/(n^2+r) = 1/(n+(r/n)) = 0.$ Since this is true for any term, and limits are distributive over addition, the limit should be zero.
But this is wrong. Why?

Comment: In MathJax, $\infty$ is `\infty`.

Comment: You cannot carelessly distribute when the series is *bound by* the limit variable .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all let's get the terminology correct: "distribute" refers to a property of two binary operations such as addition and multiplication,
$$a(b+c)=ab+ac\ .$$
Limits do not fall into this category.  You might say that "limits preserve addition" or "limits respect addition" or "the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits".

What this means, more formally, is that
$$\lim(a_n+b_n)=\lim a_n+\lim b_n\ .$$
To put it even more carefully,

> if $\lim a_n$ and $\lim b_n$ both exist, then $\lim(a_n+b_n)$ exists, and
>   $$\lim(a_n+b_n)=\lim a_n+\lim b_n\ .$$

You can easily extend this to the limit of a sum of three terms, or four, or any fixed number.  However, in your example you have a sum of $n$ terms, which is not a fixed number - it increases as $n$ increases.  So you have a situation in which your terms are getting smaller and smaller, but you are adding up more and more of them: so it should make sense intuitively that the sum might not tend to zero.

An example which works in much the same way as yours but with easier calculations:
$$\eqalign{
  \lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(\frac{n}{n^2}+\frac{2n}{2n^2}+\frac{3n}{3n^2}+\cdots
    +\frac{n.n}{n.n^2}\Bigr)
  &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\cdots
    +\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)\cr
  &=\lim_{n\to\infty}1\cr
  &=1\ ,\cr}$$
even though each term inside the brackets tends to zero as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

$$\frac {n^2}{n^2+n}\le\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {n}{n^2+k} \le \frac {n^2}{n^2+1}$$

Squeeze.

Comment: Why is what I have done wrong?

Comment: @xasthor Each term goes to zero but the number of terms goes to $+\infty $.you will get an indeterminate form $0\times +\infty $.